# Replace :D emoticons, except inside ":D"

Tags: php, regex, pcre, emoticons

I have:

```
$txt = ':D :D ":D" :D:D:D:D';
```

I want to  `preg_replace` all `:D` to `^` and if `":D"` then not replace.

```
===> output: '^ ^ ":D" ^^^^';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(*SKIP)(*F) Magic**

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*F)|:D~', '^', $yourstring);
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/24), see the substitutions in the bottom pane.

This problem is a classic case of the technique explained in this question to ["regex-match a pattern, excluding..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `"quotes"` then deliberately fails, after which the engine skips to the next position in the string. So the quotes are neutralized. The right side matches `:D`, and we know they are the right ones because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)
- [Article about matching a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **negative lookahead and lookbehind**,

```
(?<!\"):D(?!\")
```

It matches `:D` which is not preceded by `"`(double quotes) and followed by `"`. Then the matched characters are replaced by `^`

```
<?php
$string = ':D :D ":D" :D:D:D:D';
$pattern = "~(?<!\"):D(?!\")~";
$replacement = "^";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?> //=> ^ ^ ":D" ^^^^
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mM7gM9/1)